Electrical modular switch screwless cover plate
I had fitted my house with Legrand Electrical screwless switch cover plate. The problem is it is such a pain to remove i.e. put a flat screwdriver and twist. The painful part is also that the snap seems to be fragile and gets worn out/breaks. What are your opinions on this? Is there something I can do to make it less painful to remove?

Here he is also using flat screwdriver: https://youtu.be/uQhdSL9KJf8?si=DbK2w6U1mS1Hj-3k but he is doing the task with quite ease.

Try a putty knife instead of a screwdriver. Start at a corner.

How often are you taking your switch plates off that the snaps break from wearing out?

@Triplefault: I tried to remove once or twice to check some wiring inside and I the snaps flap break. They sit very tight for some reason.

TANSTAAFL
Exposed screws may be ugly, but they work. Anything hidden is a tradeoff between form and function.

I never understood plastic snap on design and kind of hate it. Plastics tend to get brittle over time and have a tendency to break and a nightmare for repair.

Usually for stuff like this I tend to buy a few extra for backup assuming it's going to break, same with LED light fixtures and cars.

If the cover plates are installed properly, (the bases are not so tight that they warp.) the top covers come of easily with a small flat blade screwdriver inserted in the notch and twisted.
If this is not working for you you probably have the base too tight.

The bases are metal plates. They didn't warp but the plates sit very tight. They come off ok but if I remove it once or twice, the snap inner flap gets worn out.

I have some of these in my home.  Installed them in 2015...have  had to take the outer cover off to paint walls.  Never had a problem but they are not made for multiple on/off rotations.
